# Replacing substring using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace a substring with pattern ”xx kr” or ”xx.xx kr” (where x is a digit) with  ”SEK xx” / ”SEK xx.xx”.

example: This item costs 34.55 kr => this item costs SEK 34.55

I have started with a method in my class:

```
/* Uses regex pattern to replace this pattern*/
private void replacePatternInLine(String line){

    line = line.replaceAll("regex", "SEK");
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

but i dont know if i am on the right track. If I am any help on what regex to use I would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a regex for this. If it's always in the format `xx kr` or `xx.xx kr` I would just use replace and then concatenate:

```
line.replaceAll(" kr", "");
line = "SEK " + line;
```

Comment: I was  not very clear maby but i am reading one line at a time from a file. so the format is a substring.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following *regex (using [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html))* :

```
([\d.]+)\s*kr
```

*see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/uiyOHQ/2)***

**Java**

```
private void replacePatternInLine(String line){
    line = line.replaceAll("([\\d.]+)\\s*kr", "SEK $1");
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Thank u ! thats a great demo

Comment: what if you have multiple blanks after the digits and want to replace it anyway? is there anyway to ignore multiple blanks that is?

Comment: i did but i dont think it will show since my rep is below 15

Comment: @Fanny yes, it will. it has nothing to do with rep. *note: you can only accept after 5 min of the answer been posted* so, maybe you did within 5 min. try now. :-)